# Gamecenter leaderboard group is not in sync

Tags: ios, game-center-leaderboard

I have a game that has been live on iTunes for about a month, and it has 16 leaderboards  (all full with scores now).
I decided that I wanted to create a free version of the app, that shares the same leaderboards.

So, I changed the leaderboards the paid app uses over to a group, and updated all the leaderboard names with "grp.*".  That change is now live, and everything is looking great, the leaderboards are still full with scores.

Now, yesterday, I released the free version of my app, also using the group leaderboards. It took all day for the app to finally show up in the appstore. This morning, when I downloaded the app, and looked at the leaderboards, they are empty, except for a few scores.

I know the code is pointing to the exact same leaderboard names, as the 2 versions of the game are built from the same exact code.  I double checked itunes connect, and it shows the 2 apps are sharing the same group leaderboards.

So I'm not sure what is going on.  Does it take a while for the scores to sync? Or is something really wrong?